# Why do my tomcat servers start as service automcatically after I stop them manually?

Tags: tomcat7, tomcat8

I have two Tomcat servers runnning as services on one Win10 Server machine. Tomcat 7 und tomcat8. Why do they start automatically after I stop then manually using "services.msc"?

Comment: Are you certain they are actually stopping correctly? You can see that in the logs?

Comment: in my Catalina log file which is set to "fine" I see no indication of a stopped service.12-Jan-2018 11:34:12.299 INFO [http-apr-8080-exec-8] de.ipsyscon.service.session.SimpleSessionHandler.updateSession Update Usersession for R2lzYWRtaW4=

Comment: But you see it restarting? Can you post say a half page of the log file, while you try to stop the service a couple of times? Sorry for delay replying I was away for weekend. Have you tried stopping and starting from the command line?

Comment: I have tried both from services.msc and from a batch script which calls a net stop command. From both methods, I see the service apparently stop, but when a look a couple of minutes later, it shows that it is running.Ill send a log from work tomorrow